# TensorFlow: Why is my Keras callback monitor value not available?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, callback

I use TensorFlow 1.12. I try to fit a model using Keras callbacks:

```
checkpoint_full = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath='model/dir/model.{epoch:02d}.hdf5', monitor='val_dice_loss', save_best_only=True, mode="min")
tensorboard = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='/media/nfs/7_raid/ebos/models/fcn/logs/', write_graph=False)
history = model.fit(train,
                    steps_per_epoch=int(np.ceil(num_samples / float(BATCH_SIZE))),
                    epochs=NUM_EPOCHS,
                    validation_data=val,
                    verbose=0,
                    callbacks=[checkpoint_full, tensorboard])
```

However, this throws the following error:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Can save best model only with val_dice_loss available, skipping.
```

Firstly, I do not understand how the string given to `monitor` is being resolved. I'm following two guides on Keras ([1](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/samples/outreach/blogs/segmentation_blogpost/image_segmentation.ipynb), [2](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras)), and both supply string names which aren't referenced anywhere else in their code. I assume these specify strings which the user can later use to retrieve the development of performance after training, rather than specify which metric `fit` is supposed to monitor? If so, why is it saying that the value isn't available?

Secondly, answers to similar questions all point out that the problem is the absence of validation data. However, I am pretty sure that I am supplying `fit` with data, as evidenced by looping through `val` and counting the number of records. What am I doing wrong?

For reference, my datasets are generated like this:

```
def train_sample_fetcher():
    return sample_fetcher()

def val_sample_fetcher():
    return sample_fetcher(is_validations=True)

def sample_fetcher(is_validations=False):
    sample_names = [filename[:-4] for filename in os.listdir(DIR_DATASET + "ndarrays/")]
    if not is_validations: sample_names = sample_names[:int(len(sample_names) * TRAIN_VAL_SPLIT)]
    else: sample_names = sample_names[int(len(sample_names) * TRAIN_VAL_SPLIT):]
    for sample_name in sample_names:
        rgb = tf.image.decode_jpeg(tf.read_file(DIR_DATASET + sample_name + ".jpg"))
        rgb = tf.image.resize_images(rgb, (HEIGHT, WIDTH))
        #d = tf.image.decode_jpeg(tf.read_file(DIR_DATASET + "depth/" + sample_name + ".jpg"))
        #d = tf.image.resize_images(d, (HEIGHT, WIDTH))
        #rgbd = tf.concat([rgb,d], axis=2)
        onehots = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.load(DIR_DATASET + "ndarrays/" + sample_name + ".npy"), dtype=tf.float32)
        yield rgb, onehots

train = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator=train_sample_fetcher, output_types=(tf.uint8, tf.uint8))
#train = train.repeat()
train = train.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
#train = train.shuffle(10)
val = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator=val_sample_fetcher, output_types=(tf.uint8, tf.uint8))
```

My loss function looks as follows:

```
def dice_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    smooth = 1.
    y_true_f = tf.reshape(y_true, [-1]) # Flatten
    y_pred_f = tf.reshape(y_pred, [-1]) # Flatten
    intersection = tf.reduce_sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    dice_coefficient = (2. * intersection + smooth) / (tf.reduce_sum(y_true_f) + tf.reduce_sum(y_pred_f) + smooth)
    loss = 1 - dice_coefficient
    return loss
```

I perform semantic segmentation, and the dice loss is calculated per pixel.

Comment: Which loss and metrics are you giving your model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monitor `'val_loss'` since your loss function is already set to your custom dice loss function.

The `monitor` parameter expects a metric. `'loss'` is always available, and if you have validation data, so is `'val_loss'`. Some folks like to use `'accuracy'` and the validation therefor. If you had a custom metric function like sensitivity called (for example) `sensitivity_deluxe()`, you could include `sensitivity_deluxe` in the array of metrics in `compile()`, and it would be available to any callbacks referencing it in their `monitor` field. Any time you have validation data, you can prefix the metric string with 'val_'.

Example:

```
model.compile(loss=my_loss_function(), optimizer='Adam', metrics=[sensitivity_deluxe])
reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', patience=3, mode='min')
earlystop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_sensitivity_deluxe', patience=5, mode='max')
model.fit(X, y, validation_split=0.5, callbacks=[earlystop, reduce_lr])
```

I can't speak to your second question regarding validation without seeing your `fit()` function, but it looks like you're probably fine since you set up separate generators.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification(s)! One thing I still don´t understand is why the loss function is passed directly to the metrics field in .compile(), but callbacks refer to those functions in strings. Does TensorFlow parse those strings and somehow connect it to the right loss function?

Comment: Yeah! You got it right, and you're also correct that it isn't intuitive. In the case of loss, the string representation remains 'loss' whether it's custom or not, because in `compile(loss=...)` it became known by that name. Otherwise, for custom metrics, the string name is specific, as in the case of theoretical custom metric function `sensitivity_deluxe()` above. The counter-intuitive part is having the function name become a string *under the hood,* but it does work that way. I suspect the reason `loss` is separate from the `metrics` array is because it (unlike any others) is mandatory.